# How to read data of url response into string array in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a url and when I open the url in python using below code,

```
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read() 
print(data)
```

i get a data like this

b'{"status": "success", "data": {"candles": [["2016-03-01T09:15:00+0530",1199,1243.35,1195,1232.9,150747],["2016-03-02T09:15:00+0530",1240,1259.8,1233.9,1243.25,140876],["2016-03-03T09:15:00+0530",1245.7,1259.8,1233,1254.15,226023],["2016-03-04T09:15:00+0530",1255,1256,1232,1239.35,189317],["2016-03-08T09:15:00+0530",1239.1,1254.95,1231.1,1241.15,151748],["2016-03-09T09:15:00+0530",1237.3,1249.7,1233.25,1243.75,304618],["2016-03-10T09:15:00+0530",1248,1250,1226.1,1230.35,157799]]}}'

This data actually represent time, open, high, low , close, volume of a stock. I want to transform these data in data in two dimensional array in most efficient manner?

Kindly tell how to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably just want to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

```
import requests
data = requests.get(url).json()['candles']
```

Answer (score 0):

The response looks like json, so load it up and manipulate the dict data as you want:

```
import json
import urllib2

def process_data(data):
    ''' Process in the most efficient manner '''
    pass

data = json.loads(urllib2. urlopen(url))
if data['status'] == 'success':
    process_data(data['data'])
```